# Uncrustify obj-c: Add newline between parameters in function declaration

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uncrustify

I am looking for some configuration to make this code

```
- (void)myFunctionWithParameter:(NSString *)param1 secondParameter:(NSString *)param2
{

}
```

to:

```
- (void)myFunctionWithParameter:(NSString *)param1 
                secondParameter:(NSString *)param2
{

}
```

The alignment is align_oc_decl_colon. I am looking for a property to add **newline** between parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can try the nl_func_def_args option, setting it to force or to add a newline.